# How to check for DBNull in C++ - ADO recordset fields?

Tags: c++, ado

I was trying to retrieve data from SQL Server via ADO in C++  and how can I check the Null Values the recordset fields? thre is no IsNUll() function?

Comment: IIRC fieldp->Value.vt == VT_NULL

Answer (score 6):

Testing for DBNull in a C++ ADO record set involves checking the `fieldpointer->Value` property, which is of type `VARIANT`. To test for null variant values, you check the `vt` field, which for null values is `VT_NULL`.

So to test for DBNull, check `fieldpointer->Value.vt == VT_NULL`